# How to Clean Uninstall Ubuntu 12 from free DOS laptop

Tags: uninstall

Hi I bought a laptop with free DOS and have tried Ubuntu 12 on it for few weeks. Have had lots of problem with it and many applications. I really can't make it to work and need this machine for my business fast! No offend to Ubuntu community, I just need this computer to work then will consider install it on dual boot mode. Please help.

Comment: Please add some detail.  Brand/model of laptop, and what if anything you *specifically* can **not** get to work. *If you just need to re-install, they try that first.*

Comment: Notebook: MSI GE60-i547W7H (GE60 Series)
Processor: Intel Core i5 3210M
Graphics Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M

Comment: Problems: 1) I'm not good with computer, just end user 2) Can't get all drivers package that come with the laptop installed on ubuntu. This includes THX sound system, Nvidia screen driver, Turbo fan driver (it is running at turbo speed at all time) and 3) LibreOffice crash all the time. 4) Firefox crash all everytime I search and may be more..

Comment: Try re-install 2 times wasted a couple days on it. I need the machine for work fast since my old machine's screen was dead, so I went to get a Window 8 OEM OS. I want to make sure that my Window installation will be totally clean. Then later on will try to install ubuntu with its own partition.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda wrong forum but... download the OS you would rather have (debian?) and install making sure to use all of the disk. Thats it!

Comment: I had Ubuntu 12 installed before Windows. After some search, I found that install Windows after Ubuntu is harder than vice versa. So want to do the following steps: 1) clean uninstall ubuntu (keep DOS if possible),  2) Install Windows 8 on main partition, 3) Install Ubuntu on another partition

Comment: @MeeNYC In your question you seemed to indicate you did not want ubuntu at all and you didn't mention windows. But from my experience install linux last whenever possible because grub (typical linux bootloader) is able to find and handle virtually any OS